# how to bind observable array items

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I am unable to get the children field values in the html.Below is the code."results" is an array with which I get from an web service. values are pushed into children array and I am able to alert out succesfully but not able to get them in html when binded.

view:

```
 <h2>People</h2>
 <ul data-bind="foreach: people">
 <li>
<div>
    <span data-bind="text: name"> </span> has <span data-bind='text: children().length'>&nbsp;</span> children:    
</div>
<ul data-bind="foreach: {data: children, as: 'child'}">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: child.name"> </span> 
          <span data-bind="text: child.age"> </span> 
          <span data-bind="text: child.weight"> </span> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

viewmodel:

```
 var Person = function(name, children, len) {
    this.name = name;
    this.children = new ko.observableArray(children);
    this.children.push({
       name: children.name;
       age: children.age;
       weight: children.weight;
    });
  }
 }

 var viewModel = function() {
  var this = self;
  self.callServicekids("10",retKids(results) {
     for (var i=0; i<results.length ; i++){
       new person("Annabelle", results[i] );
     }
   },errorHandler);
 }


ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I noticed that your html is not valid here `<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
 <li>`. Since it's vital when using knockout, firstly I would recommend to fix this.

Comment: You have left out where you are retaining the `new person("Annabelle", results[i] );` within your viewmodel. The html suggests `people` which is not present in what you have provided. Also, if results is an array of children, you shouldn't be iterating over it outside of the "parent".

Comment: You have some suspect javascript in your sample..  `var this = self;`.  Also when pushing a new item to children(I'm assuming children variable is an array), you read `children.name`, `children.age` and `children.weight`, since children is an array then those 3 properties will be undefined.